# How to use another author name in the text than in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I use Biblatex with the `authoryear` style.
I would like to show the abbreviation of an author's name (actually an organization) when using the `\citet` command, but I would to have the fully name in the bibliography.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `shortauthor`. The `shortauthor` field can contain a 'shorter' (abbreviated) version of the `author` field. There is also `shorteditor`, which does the same thing for `editor`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{nasa,
  author      = {{National Aeronautics and Space Administration}},
  shortauthor = {NASA},
  title       = {How to Fake the Moon Landing},
  date        = {1960},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{nasa} or \textcite{nasa}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citation: "NASA (1960)", Bibliography: "National Aeronautics and Space Administration (1960)"]

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!